# Regex (.NET) to find a pattern between two other patterns

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
DOG[i want to look for specific hits of stuff here]
```

I want to match any occurrences of the words "look" or "stuff" that occur between the opening `DOG[` and the closing `]`

I know I can write a rege like `(?<=DOG\[).*?(?=\])` to find *all text* between the opening and closing bits, but I want to look for only specific words between these openers and closers.

How can I do this?

Comment: It is .NET, use `(?<=DOG\[[^][]*?)(?:look|stuff)(?=[^][]*])`

Comment: You have no idea how much you've just helped me. Do you mind writing a full-on answer where you can explain your code in a little more detail? I want to understand it a little more.

Comment: There are alternatives and workarounds for this, too, but I can't show you any since you have not explained what you plan to do with the matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in .NET regex you may use patterns matching strings of unknown length in lookbehinds, you may use

```
(?<=DOG\[[^][]*?)(?:look|stuff)(?=[^][]*])
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3DDOG%5C%5B%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*%3F%29%28%3F%3Alook%7Cstuff%29%28%3F%3D%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*%5D%29&i=DOG%5Bi%20want%20to%20look%20for%20specific%20hits%20of%20stuff%20here%5D).

Here,

- `(?<=DOG\[[^][]*?)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediately preceded with `DOG[` and any 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `(?:look|stuff)` - `look` or `stuff`
- `(?=[^][]*])` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with any 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]`.